# simplemodal 1.4.4 not giving removeExpression error in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, simplemodal

I am using simplemodal by Eric Martin and am getting an error in IE9

"Object doesn't support property or method 'removeExpression'"

I read that this was an issue relating to IE9 removing support for dynamic properties, but that this was fixed back in version 1.4.3

Has anyone else encountered an issue since and if so is there a fix?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

recent 1.4.5 fixes the 'removeExpression' issues